# pig replicated join on multiple fields with OR

Tags: mysql, apache-pig

I have the following requirement -

I have the following records in one file A -

> content       X        Y
>
> c1            A1                A2
>
> c2            null/empty        A2
>
> c3            A1            null/empty
>
> c4            B1            null/empty
>
> c5       null/empty            B2
>
> c6            B1               B2
>
> c7            D1               D2
>
> c8            F1          null/empty
>
> c9            G1          null/empty

I have another small file B with the content -

> X       Y
>
> A1       A2
>
> B1       B2

Now I need to do a set A-B join so that i get the following result -

> content        X        Y
>
> c7            D1      D2
>
> c8            F1    null/empty
>
> c9            G1    null/empty

I am currently using replicated join as my B file can be fit in memory. However I am not sure how to do either/or/or both join here. I am not so comfortable with db queries.

Regards,
Aditya

Comment: The field values of X - A1, B1, can these occur in field Y ?

Comment: did not get what you mean by X-A1..

Comment: In file B, you have fields by name X and Y and the values of field X are A1 and B1, can this value be seen in field Y or its specific to X. Can the values - A1 and B1 be seen in field Y ?

Comment: The values in X are specific to X and Y specific to Y.

Comment: Also I figured out that 2 replicated JOINS with filters will help solve me this problem. In the first JOIN i will JOIN on X and then FILTER on is null . I will then take the results and do another replicated JOIN on Y and again FILTER is null. Lemme know if that looks correct.

Comment: Sharing a thought worth contemplating, as you said the values in field X and Y are unique we can read and create a single field having both values and join once to achieve the objective. Check answer for an use case.

Comment: Single JOIN will definitely be better. Lemme go though the solution you provided and get back. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think substract could help here : Just try !

> https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_pig/apache_pig_subtract.htm
>   https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#subtract

Comment: Substract will load both in memory. Since only one of my data size is smaller in size 'replicated' makes sense in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The following are the intermediate and final result of the 2 replicated JOIN and FILTER -

```
cat ids_test.json
{"A":"a1","B":"a2"}

cat part-test
{"content":"both_A_a1_B_a2","meta":{"A":"a1","B":"a2"}}
{"content":"only_B_a2","meta":{"A":"","B":"a2"}}
{"content":"only_A_a1","meta":{"A":"a1","B":""}}
{"content":"both_A_b1_B_b2","meta":{"A":"b1","B":"b2"}}
{"content":"only_A_c1","meta":{"A":"c1","B":""}}

cat /tmp/j1/part-m-00000
{"user_data::json":{"meta":"{B=a2, A=a1}","content":"both_A_a1_B_a2"},"ids::json":{"B":"a2","A":"a1"}}
{"user_data::json":{"meta":"{B=a2, A=}","content":"only_B_a2"},"ids::json":null}
{"user_data::json":{"meta":"{B=, A=a1}","content":"only_A_a1"},"ids::json":{"B":"a2","A":"a1"}}
{"user_data::json":{"meta":"{B=b2, A=b1}","content":"both_A_b1_B_b2"},"ids::json":null}
{"user_data::json":{"meta":"{B=, A=c1}","content":"only_A_c1"},"ids::json":null}

cat /tmp/j1_filter/part-m-00000
{"user_data::json":{"meta":"{B=a2, A=}","content":"only_B_a2"},"ids::json":null}
{"user_data::json":{"meta":"{B=b2, A=b1}","content":"both_A_b1_B_b2"},"ids::json":null}
{"user_data::json":{"meta":"{B=, A=c1}","content":"only_A_c1"},"ids::json":null}

cat /tmp/j2/part-m-00000
{"J1_FILTER::user_data::json":{"meta":"{B=a2, A=}","content":"only_B_a2"},"J1_FILTER::ids::json":null,"ids::json":{"B":"a2","A":"a1"}}
{"J1_FILTER::user_data::json":{"meta":"{B=b2, A=b1}","content":"both_A_b1_B_b2"},"J1_FILTER::ids::json":null,"ids::json":null}
{"J1_FILTER::user_data::json":{"meta":"{B=, A=c1}","content":"only_A_c1"},"J1_FILTER::ids::json":null,"ids::json":null}

cat /tmp/results/part-m-00000
{"J1_FILTER::user_data::json":{"meta":"{B=b2, A=b1}","content":"both_A_b1_B_b2"}}
{"J1_FILTER::user_data::json":{"meta":"{B=, A=c1}","content":"only_A_c1"}}
```

The following is the code -

```
user_data = LOAD 'part-test' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-nestedLoad') as (json:map[]);
ids = LOAD 'ids_test.json' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-nestedLoad') as (json:map[]);
J1 = JOIN user_data BY json#'meta'#'A' LEFT OUTER, ids BY json#'A' USING 'replicated';

rmf /tmp/j1
store J1 into '/tmp/j1' USING JsonStorage;

J1_FILTER = FILTER J1 BY ids::json is null;

rmf /tmp/j1_filter
store J1_FILTER into '/tmp/j1_filter' USING JsonStorage;

J2 = JOIN J1_FILTER BY user_data::json#'meta'#'B' left outer, ids BY json#'B' USING 'replicated';

rmf /tmp/j2
store J2 into '/tmp/j2' USING JsonStorage;

J2_FILTER = FILTER J2 BY ids::json is null;

RESULTS = FOREACH J2_FILTER GENERATE J1_FILTER::user_data::json;
--filtered_ids = FOREACH user_data_MINUS_ids GENERATE user_data AS data;
--DUMP filtered_ids;
rmf /tmp/results
store RESULTS into '/tmp/results' USING JsonStorage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thought is to have a single field having both the values of fields X and Y from b.txt so that we can go for a replicated join only once.

**a.txt**

```
c1 A1 A2
c2  A2
c3 A1 
c4 B1 
c5  B2
c6 B1 B2
c7 D1 D2
c8 F1 
c9 G1
```

**b.txt**

```
A1 A2
B1 B2
```

**PigSnippet**

```
adataset = LOAD 'a.txt' USING PigStorage(' ') AS (content:chararray,key1:chararray,key2:chararray);
bdataset = LOAD 'b.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (key:chararray);

keys = FOREACH bdataset GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(key,' ')) AS key;

SPLIT adataset INTO null_keys IF(key1 IS NULL AND key2 IS NULL),
                    not_null_keys IF NOT(key1 IS NULL AND key2 IS NULL);

joined_data = JOIN not_null_keys BY (key1 IS NULL ? key2 : key1) LEFT, keys BY key USING 'replicated';

req_data = FILTER joined_data BY keys::key IS NULL;

DUMP req_data;
```

**Output :**

```
(c7,D1,D2,)
(c8,F1,,)
(c9,G1,,)
```